# Componente que permite realizar un tutorial guiado sobre el uso de mi aplicación web?

Tags: javascript, html, css3

Estoy buscando un ejemplo de un sitio o una librería que tenga un componente mediante el cual permita realizar un tutorial guiado en tiempo real, sobre como usar la aplicación...

Ejemplo que se vaya seleccionando y muestre información extra sobre los cuadros de texto o botones y que acciones realiza cada uno.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No sé si es exactamente el que viste, pero éste te puede servir, es bastante conocido http://introjs.com/

Lo que hace es dar una especie de sombreado a toda la página pero dejando libre la sección que quieres mostrar. Entra al enlace, click en demo para tener la idea 100% clara si es que no me he dejado entender.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Puede proporcionar alguna explicación de lo que hace?

Comment: @Riker Lo que hace es dar una especie de sombreado a toda la página pero dejando libre la sección que quieres mostrar. Entra al enlace, click en demo para tener la idea 100% clara si es que no me he dejado entender :D saludos!

Comment: muchas gracias, :) , me fue de mucha utilidad.

Comment: @cristina-carrasco-angulo Por favor dinos como haces esos gifs, son muy útiles

Comment: Claro @Jorius es con la aplicación: [ScreenToGif](http://www.screentogif.com/), si esta genial :-)